# Modeling With Single Reference

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image, workflow

My question is? how to model this kinda complex model with single reference? and its rotated about 20degrees that even more harder, any pro tip,advice, help will be highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Hi. It might be useful to state what current problem you are having/think you will have using a single reference.

Comment: Its hard model this kinda complex stuff with rotated angle, not back, front ,left, right, so how to start modeling the right way this kind model? how to match right proportions?

Comment: Hello :). I'd break it down into separate objects first. Starting with the tiny simple lights where the proportions are clear... and then modeling more complex shapes. To get the right view angle, the FSpy addon might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to guess how the back, bottom and part of the top look.

As far as proportions go, a box in orthographic projection at 20 degrees means that it projects about 93% of actual length of the front and 34% of the side. I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284741/is-there-a-more-precise-way-to-determine-the-percentage-of-actual-length-of-a-pr) and got the answer for all the angles of a plane rotated in one axis.

[image]

As a note the vertical stays at actual length and only the horizontal is shrinking. From the lines I measured, the side distance distance between the points is 2.15 times greater the the front one. However, it’s necessary to understand the form. For example, the back of the side is occluded, and the limit of the back is closer then that of the contour.

If you are dealing with more complex angles, I gave an answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82249/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-2d-images-to-single-3d-model/132775#132775) about how to approach proportions. Hope this brief answer helps.